# How to solve this ValueError in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
for x in (df.index):
        if(df.loc[x]['hour']==9):
            print(True)
```

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Comment: can you share an example of `df` running this code seems to work just fine for me with a dataframe with a column names 'hour' containing integers between 1 and 20

Comment: @Patrick https://imgur.com/9pnYOu3

Comment: @KamalKannan you should add it as text/code in your original question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue here is that the index is not unique, this is causing `df.loc[x]['hour']` to return a Series not a single value it would be better to simply loop over the values you are checking

```
for x in (df.hour):
    if(x==9):
        print(True)
```

Output

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: Yes. I understand what happened there now. Thanks man.